# How I can extrude icing of donut without intersecting meshes?

Tags: modeling

[image: intersection]

Snap has *Face* option. I selected two vertices and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude. What I doing wrong? In famous Youtube tutorial it works fine.

Comment: Solidify modifier perhaps?

Comment: Hard to tell from this screenshot. Activate [Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPknY.png) in the viewport overlays and have a look from the side. It looks like the extruded verts are on the surface but there is not enough geometry for the icing to follow the donut's shape. So they might intersect.